# How to modify a Pandas Column filled text

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to edit a Pandas dataframe column filled with text. Basically applying some editing functions(slicing, extraction and so on).

I am using writing the fucntion and applying the map function on the column to accomplish that.
    df["Time taken"] = df["details"].map(somefunc)

However it seems I cant edit the text as Pandas stores the datatype in "object" not "string".

I tried using astype(str) but it still stays "object".

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: `object` is the correct `dtype` for `str`, so this is correct behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform string operations on Pandas series by appending .str to the series name.  Here are some examples:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 'Label1', 'B': '$12.00'},
...                    {'A': 'Label2', 'B': '$14.00'},
...                    {'A': 'Label1', 'B': '$9.00'},
...                    {'A': 'Label2', 'B': '$8.00'}])
>>> df.B.str.replace('$','')
0    12.00
1    14.00
2     9.00
3     8.00
Name: B, dtype: object
>>> df.A.str[-1:]
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
Name: A, dtype: object
>>> df.A.str[1:]
0    abel1
1    abel2
2    abel1
3    abel2
Name: A, dtype: object
>>> df.B.str.len()
0    6
1    6
2    5
3    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Pandas documentation: [Working with Text Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html)